# How to add an argument in array and align functions?

Tags: align, arrays

So I have been trying to reproduce this lately : [image]

And this is the closest I've got so far :
[image]

This is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}’’
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
\Phi\colon & (l^\infty(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C}),\| \cdot \|_{l^\infty} & \longrightarrow & ((l^1(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C}),\| \cdot \|_{l^1}) \\
    
                  & u_n = (u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}          & \longmapsto     & 
  \begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}l@{\;}l}
    \Phi\colon & (l^1(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
    & x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \longmapsto \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty u_n x_n
  \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, as you noticed the argument in **yellow** is missing in my version and I can't find why.

Also , the lines `\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}` and `\begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}l@{\;}l}` and the command `\column` weren't written by me and I honestly don't really understand what those long arguments in `begin{array}`and `\column` do. So if someone could enlighten me it would be great.

In the end , if someone could show how to do both versions with and without the **bracket** I would very much appreciate since I am quite confused .

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: They are column specifications. See e.g. page 87 of LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual

Comment: You wrote, "the argument in yellow is missing in my version and I can't find [out] why." That would be because you have *not* provided code that would generate the highlighted material.

Comment: Indeed but that's because when I tried to add the argument there my code wouldn't compile, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch from 4 to just 3 columns in each `array`.

[image]

I've used `\rightarrow` and `\mapsto` instead of `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto`, in order to better approximate the screenshot you posted. Obviously, you are entirely free to use `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto` if that is what you wish to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % mathtools loads amsmath automatically
\usepackage{array}     % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % col. type for binary and relational operators
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}   % amssymb loads amsfonts automatically

% \usepackage{calrsfs} % not needed for this example
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % don't load packages twice
%\usepackage{graphicx} % not needed for this example
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat} % not needed for this example
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} % not needed for this example
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand\blanknorm{\norm{{}\cdot{}}} % 'generic norm'

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{rCl}
  \Phi\colon\ 
  (l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C}), \blanknorm_{l^{\infty}}) & 
  \rightarrow & 
  \bigl(  % I would enlarge the 'outer' pair of parentheses
     {( l^1(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C}), \blanknorm_{l^1} )}', 
     \blanknorm_{(l^1)'} 
  \bigr )   \\[2\jot] % end of row 1: add a bit of vertical whitespace
  u_n = (u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} & 
  \mapsto & 
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{rCl}
      \Phi(u)\colon\qquad l^1(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{C}) &
      \rightarrow & 
      \mathbb{C} \\[\jot]
      x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} &
      \mapsto & 
      \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} u_n x_n
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```